# Multivariate (Polynomial?) Regression

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to solve one problem, I'm not sure how to do it...

Here is my problem (related to Heat transfer/Fluid mechanics) that I tried to simplify :

- I have a few independents measurements $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ and $y$

  - These datas give me some parameters, using some constants :

    - $P_1 = x_1 + i$
    - $P_2 = j * x_1*x_2 $
    - $P_3 = x_3^\frac{1}{2} + k$
    - $P_4 = x_4^4 - \frac{x_3^4}{l}$
  - Then I have : $$y = a_1 * P_1 + a_2* P_2 + a_3 * P_3 + a_4 * P_4$$

My questions are :

1. How can I **find the coefficients**  $a_1, a_2, a_3$ and $a_4$ (using python) ?

   - Shall calculate all $P_i$ and make a **linear regression** on the formula ?
   - Shall expand everything and make a **polynomial regression** on $x_i$ ?
   - Shall i do **something else** than regression (ANN, etc.) ?
   - Am I missing something here ?
2. What should I do in case of one $P_i$ is *dependent* ? 
   For example : $P_5 = x_1(x_2+1) $ (which can be extracted from $P_1$ and $P_2$) with  $y = ... + a_5 * P_5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can calculate pi and run linear regression. You should not be confused about the term "polynomial regression". A regression on polynomial basis expansion (even some of the terms do not exists) can be called polynomial regression.
2. Drop the dependent variables or add [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics))

Comment: Another point I forgot to ask... If already know that some coefficient are between such and such values, in python is there any way to express it ?